# When should I use prepared statements exactly?

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo, parameter-passing

I want to know, can I just use prepared statements one time?

Here is my script:

```
$stm = $db->prepare("UPDATE
                     qanda AS ans1
                     JOIN qanda AS ans2 ON ans2.related = ans1.related
                     JOIN qanda AS ques ON ans2.related = ques.id
                     SET ans1.acceptedanswer = 1,
                         ans1.aadate = IF( ans1.id <> ?, ans1.aadate, ?)
                     WHERE ques.author_id = ? AND ans2.author_id = ? 
                                        ");
$stm->execute(array($answer_id, time(), $_SESSION["Id"], $author_id));
$done = $stm->rowCount();

if ($done){
    /* I don't use prepared statement here */
    $stm1 = $db->prepare("UPDATE user SET rep = rep + 15 WHERE id = $author_id");
    $stm1->execute();
}
```

As you see I didn't use *prepared statement* for second query. Because I did it for first query and if first query is working then I'm sure arguments are valid and don't need to bind them by *prepared statement*.

Please don't ask me *why you don't want to use prepared statemen't for second query, because the reason is too long.*

So what I'm doing is correct? Isn't there any security problem?

Comment: `Please don't ask me why you don't want to use prepared statemen't for second query, because the reason is too long.` not to burst your bubble, but you **are** already using a prepared statement (`$db->prepare(...)`)... you're just building a static one instead of properly using a placeholder and binding the parameter.

Comment: @ccKep Are you sure? `:-)` Because I don't have any problem with `prepare()` function, I just cannot pass the parameters as `:something` or `?` .. So everything is ok?

Comment: Why couldn't you? I know you said it's too long, but really it's just one extra line of code. (or a simple parameter for `->execute()`, for all that matters).

Comment: @ccKep Well my query is made dynamically .. So I don't know when should I pass what things ..

Comment: There's nothing dynamic in the code you posted above, so I guess that's not a 1:1 copy/paste of your actual code up there?

Comment: @ccKep Yes that isn't my actual code ..

Comment: In that case: Do it just like you did above... replace `$author_id` in your query with `?` and add `array($author_id)` as a parameter to `$db->execute`. If your actual query changes (for example the fields you're updating), just build that $stm1 variable inside your different code-branches and still execute it with `$stm1->execute(array($author_id));`

Comment: @ccKep Well I can't .. Because sometimes my second query needs two parameters, sometime else three parameters .. Nothing isn't constant .. That's why I'm trying  to use variables into the query directly ..

Comment: It's probably more efficient to **really** not use prepared statements then (eg. `$db->query` instead of `$db->prepare` in case your db layer has such a functionality).

Comment: @Stack if you're building the query dynamically you should also be able to add appropriate parameters to the array list used for parameters as the query is constructed. I say *should* because php-fu is lacking; you can append to an array, can't you?

Comment: To add to what @ccKep said, if you are not parameterizing your query, and not running the query repeatedly (unchanged), there is no reason to prepare.

Comment: @Uueerdo I know it is possible, but really hard for me .. My codes are weird `:-)` I cannot do anything I want ..

Comment: "/* I don't use prepared statement here */" yes you do that is a prepared statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straight answer is: yes, you can.

The reason why is actually up to you, since it's anyway good practice to use prepared statement whenever you pass values.

Also consider that, if you are not binding any parameter, it makes more sense to use the query() method, just to be explicit on the fact that you are not going to bind anything. So your second query would be

```
$stm1 = $db->query("UPDATE user SET rep = rep + 15 WHERE id = $author_id");
```

(*see http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php*)

instead of

```
$stm1 = $db->prepare("UPDATE user SET rep = rep + 15 WHERE id = $author_id");
$stm1->execute();
```

Moreover you mentioned a dynamic query, but this is not the case of your sample code. Anyway I will give you an example of how two use prepared statement also on queries dynamically generated.

It's a silly example, but should be enough to give you an idea.

Assume we have some values to update 'email', 'date_of_birth' and 'website'. Let's say we want to do some check on this data before inserting them. I'll pretend we have a valid() function already in place.

```
    $dynamic_sql = array();
    $parameters[':date_of_bird'] = $date_of_birth;

    if(valid($email)) {
        $dynamic_sql['email_sql'] = "email = :email";
        $parameters[':email'] = $email;

    }
    if(valid($website)) {
        $dynamic_sql['website_sql'] = "website = :website";
        $parameters[':website'] = $website;
    }

    if(count($dynamic_sql)>0) {
        $dynamic_sql = ','.implode($dynamic_sql);
    }

    $query = "UPDATE user
    SET date_of_birth = :date_of_birth $dynamic_sql
    WHERE
    user_id = :user_id";

    $stm = $db->prepare($query);
    $stm->execute($parameters);
```

This kind of approach will allow you to keep using prepared statement also with dynamically generated SQL.